# How to add a rule to regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Good day I have This form element

```
   <?php echo new \App\Http\Render\Form\Element\Text([
                      'value' => (isset($this->entity['str'])) ? $this->entity['str'] : '',
                      'elementName' => 'item[str]',
                      'elementID' => 'str',
                      'required' => true,
                      'class' => 'form-control',                   
                        'attributes' => [
                            'data-msg-required' => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihre Straße inkl. Hausnummer an.',//Bitte geben Sie Ihre Stra&szlig;e ein.
                            'regex' => "[/.*?(\d+)$/]",
                            'data-rule-minlength'=>"6",
                            'data-msg-minlength' => 'Bitte verwenden Sie keine Zahlen und Sonderzeichen.',
                            'data-msg-regex' => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihre Straße inkl. Hausnummer an.',
                        ],
                      'placeholder'=>" "
                  ]) ?>
```

As you see I use regular expression to note of error when is number epsen after the string.Please tell me Why I can not see error when I put a dot after the string? Like this case "Strabe ." How I can set the regular expression to note the error when there is no digits in the string at the end of string?

Comment: Where is the regex used? You should tag the framework.

Comment: `$` is the end of your string. Right before that you expect a digit between 0-9. If you end your string with `.` then it won't match. That being said... "Strabe" shouldn't match either.

Comment: @user3783243 Does PHP regex differ between frameworks?

Comment: If you can please give me the case of code that I need Please, Actually I dont understand yet this logic, also ask to explain more clearly if it possible

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, even PHP's syntax varies by the PHP function. For example some require delimiters, some don't. They all use PCRE, or to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I think user3783243 is suggesting that someone familiar with this particular framework (whatever it is) may be familiar with the `class' => 'form-control', 'attributes' =>'regex'` syntax being used (and what it is specifically used for).

Answer (score -1):

Your regex pattern `[/.*?(\d+)$/]` is enclosed in `[` and `]`, which means a class of characters, so a string that contains any of the characters in between the square brackets would match your regex pattern, including a dot `.`. Slashes (`/`) are also not needed as an enclosure.

You should simply write `'regex' => ".*?(\d+)$"` instead.

Comment: They might be delimiters...unless you know the framework they are using

Comment: It's fairly obvious from the fact that a string with a dot matches, that the square brackets are part of the regex that denotes to a class of characters. Since the beginning and the end of the `regex` value are both part of the pattern, it goes without saying that this framework expects no delimiter to the regex pattern.

Comment: It auto tags users if no one else has commented. Based on the written regex I'd make no assumptions

Comment: @user3783243 Again, the OP not only posted his code but also stated the fact that a string with a dot matches. With that piece of information it's fairly straightforward to deduce that square brackets are used as part of the pattern. (Thanks for letting me know how tagging works by the way.)

Comment: Strange, you tagged me twice in that case. Guess it was really important for me to read? Anyway I don't make assumptions here. Good luck to you. I downvoted for your snidey attitude.

Comment: @user3783243 Snidey how? I've explained my thought process in a detailed and neutral way. Mind letting me know which word I used triggered your "snidey" alarm? I tagged you because it was a response to you, and I did not know if you would be notified of the response if you were not tagged. If anything you should be reported for abusing the downvote system on answers, which is meant for disagreement on answers but not on attitude. For attitude issues there's always the flag function.

Comment: `It's fairly obvious`, `it goes without saying`, `Again,`. Maybe the `(Thanks for letting me` wasn't meant to be sarcastic. Per meta `everyone is free to vote as they please.`.